# Reemplazar palabras de una columna en otra columna en un texto

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, str-replace

Estoy tratando de reemplazar palabras de una columna en otra columna en un texto:

**Texto:**

> Mientras se constataban estos retrasos, las centrales nucleares en activo han ido construyendo almacenes individuales dentro de sus instalaciones para guardar el peligroso combustible gastado de sus reactores.

**Texto columnas:**

> constatar,constataban
>
> este,estos
>
> retraso,retrasos
>
> la,las
>
> central,centrales
>
> nuclear,nucleares
>
> haber,han
>
> ir,ido
>
> construir,construyendo
>
> almacén,almacenes
>
> individual,individuales
>
> su,sus
>
> instalación,instalaciones
>
> gastar,gastado
>
> reactor,reactores
>
> metro,m
>
> segundo,s
>
> página,p
>
> actor,actores

**Script:**

```
import csv

with open('teste_es.csv', 'r') as f, open('lemas-lexemas.csv', 'r') as c:
    csv_texto = csv.reader(f)
    csv_lemas = csv.reader(c, delimiter = ',')

    for p in csv_texto:
        texto = ''.join(p)
        texto = texto.lower()

        for tokens in csv_lemas:
            lemas = tokens[0]
            lexemes = tokens[1]

            nuevo_texto = texto.replace(lexemes, lemas) 

            texto = nuevo_texto

        print(nuevo_texto)
```

**Resultado:**

> metroientrasegundo segundoe consegundotatar esegundote retrasegundoo la central nuclear en activo haber ir consegundotruir almetroacén individual dentro de segundou insegundotalación páginaara guardar el páginaeligrosegundoo cometrobusegundotible gasegundotar de segundou reactor.

El problema es que mi programa sustituye letras dentro de palabras:

**mientras** se convirtió en ***metro*ientrasegundo** porque la primera letra "m" se sustituye por "metro". Yo no sé cómo hacer que cada palabra sea reemplazada. Si que puedo usar split (), pero tengo muchas líneas en mi texto y no puedo perderlas (si hago un split () y luego un join (), yo pierdo mis líneas divididas)

Comment: Conoces las expresiones regulares? Te pueden ayudar en esta tarea. Quizás podrías hacer un intento con ellas y ponerlo por aquí. Aquí tienes un tutorial que explica expresiones regulares con python: https://platzi.com/blog/expresiones-regulares-python/

Comment: Hola marin, bienvenid@ a [es.so]. No me queda clara la estructura de 'teste_es.csv'. ¿Si es un csv que separan las comas? ¿Palabras?¿Párrafos?... Ten en cuenta que `str.replace` no tiene concepto alguno de "palabra", reemplaza subcadenas, es decir `"Ho... Hola".replace("Ho", "Co")` retorna "Co... Cola"

Comment: Sí, es un csv con dos columnas separadas por comas y el objetivo es sustituir las palabras de la segunda columna que aparecen en un texto por las palabras de la primera columna. No soy muy fuerte con expresiones regulares, pero voy a intentar. gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con lo siguiente:

```
import csv
import re

f = open("teste_es.csv", "r")
texto = f.read()
nuevo_texto = texto

with open('lemas-lexemas.csv', 'r') as c:
    csv_lemas = csv.reader(c, delimiter = ',')

    for tokens in csv_lemas:
        print(tokens)
        lema = tokens[0]
        lexema = tokens[1]
        regex = r"\b" + re.escape(lexema) + r"\b"
        nuevo_texto = re.sub(regex, lema, nuevo_texto, 0, re.IGNORECASE)

    print("Antes: " + texto + "\n")
    print("Ahora: " + nuevo_texto)
```

No necesitas leer el fichero de texto con el módulo csv. Puedes usar directamente `open` y `read`. Esto facilita la operativa más adelante.

La idea es, en el texto original, ir remplazando las palabras del csv. La clave aquí es usar el `limite de palabra` (`\b`) en el remplazo por expresión regular.

De esta manera evitarás los problemas al sustituir texto en palabras que lo engloban parcialmente (como la `s` en `Mientras` que da **metroientrasegundo**)